# why doesn't this code loop?

Tags: jquery

```
var fadeCounter = 0;

function fadeNext() {
  window.fadeCounter++;
  s = '#slide' + window.fadeCounter;
  $(s).fadeIn(1000,fadeNext);
  //forgive typos above, code works, what doesn't:
  if (window.fadeCounter == 8) window.fadeCounter = 0;
  //code will loop up to 8, then stop. why?
}

//initiate loop
fadeNext();
```

**edit:**

Demo added, at http://jsfiddle.net/AXRBh/2/
In demo, loop should reset at 20 but halts. Why?

Comment: stack overflow: why did you write a tag in the title?

Comment: @Tomalak: [SEO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions).

Comment: @KennyTM: No, that's why SO puts the first tag in the `<title>`. Writing tags in question titles is discouraged.

Comment: @Tomalak: It looks like you're asking "Stack Overflow" :p

Comment: There's probably a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do altogether. Care to explain what this function is for?

Comment: @KennyTM: That was the intention, and it was ironic. :)

Comment: code avail. at http://jsfiddle.net/AXRBh/2/ Purpose: 4-layered async slideshow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `fadeCounter` is not declared in global scope, it will not work. Make sure you define the variable outside the `document.ready` handler (or remove `window.`).

The function **does keep calling itself** (only one time, see next paragraph) but you **don't see the effect**. After the first "loop" all the elements are visible so calling a second time `fadeIn` on them has no effect.

Because they are already visible, the `fadeIn` callback is fired immediately, making the function act in a weird way: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/nZ7Mn/
In this case, the next `fadeNext` passed as callback is executed before the counter is reset:

```
  // s is already visible, so `fadeNext` is called immediately
  $(s).fadeIn(1000,fadeNext);
  // only after that the timer is reset (too late)
  if (window.fadeCounter == 8) window.fadeCounter = 0;
```

As there is not element with ID `#slide9`, calling `fadeIn` on it has no effect and the recursion stops.

As [@Cybernate already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872288/why-doesnt-this-code-loop/5872375#5872375), reversing the order of these two statements fixes the issue. However, you still won't see the effect as the elements are already visible. You just keep unnecessarily calling the function in a rapid way, which might even crash the browser.

So in order to make it working properly you should hide the elements again. Here is a bit cleaner version:

```
var max = 4;

function fadeNext(i) {
  i = i % max;
  $('body').append('<div>Current counter: ' + i + '</div>');
   $('#s' + i).fadeIn(1000,function() {
       $(this).fadeOut(1000, function(){fadeNext(i + 1)});
   });                                      
}

//initiate loop
fadeNext(0);
```

Instead of having the function accessing and changing a global variable (which can lead to some kind of "race condition" as you already experienced), pass the next index as parameter to the function.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/nZ7Mn/2/)

The big question is: What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks everyone for answers, if any one care to look at the code at jsfiddle (link in OP), I belive the cause is none of the above but chrome identifying an endless JS-loop and terminates it. FF behaves differently, but it's my best guess. Marking this post as best answer because of it's thoroughness.

Answer (score 3):

Move the counter reset right after the slide id.

```
var fadeCounter = 0;

function fadeNext() {
  window.fadeCounter++;
  s = '#slide' + window.fadeCounter;
  if (window.fadeCounter == 8) window.fadeCounter = 0;
  $(s).fadeIn(1000,fadeNext);
  //forgive typos above, code works, what doesn't:

  //code will loop up to 8, then stop. why?
}

//initiate loop
fadeNext();
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be:

```
fadeLoop(0);

function fadeLoop(id) {
  if (id <= 8) { // add "&& id >= 0" if you're pedantic
    $("#slide" + id).fadeIn(1000, fadeLoop(id+1));
  }
}
```

Comment: The function is recursive, so it is perfectly fine. Your code will make all elements visible at onces.

Comment: Add sleep(1000) at the end of the loop then.

Comment: `sleep` does not exist in JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, I've changed it to a recursive function.

Comment: @Nick. Ther's no sleep (not even workarounds that don't hang the browser) in javascript.

Comment: @Edgar Which is why I've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do exactly? Is the function repeating indefinitely?

I did this demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/AXRBh/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fadeCounter = 0;
    var time = setInterval(fadeNext, 2000);

    function fadeNext() {
       fadeCounter++;
       $('.slide').fadeOut(1000,function(){
          s = '#slide' + fadeCounter;
          $(s).fadeIn();
       });
       if (fadeCounter == 8)
          fadeCounter = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think fadeCounter variable is out of scope (inside a function?). Do this:

```
//initiate loop
$(document).ready(function(){
   window.fadeCounter = 0;  //Explicitly reference it as  a global var
   fadeNext();
});
```

Your `fadeNext()` function declaration remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the incremented variable before checking to see if it is out of range.

The ninth time through the loop your code will try to `$('#slide9').fadeIn`

[**Fiddle working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/mMDsA/)